# underscore in filename using getfiledate Package

Tags: packages, external-files

I'm trying to use the `getfiledate` package from `CTAN` to get, as sugested, the last file modification date.

I've imported correctly the package and tested with another file, named `table/classe.tex` and works perfectly.

When tested accord as following I get an error

```
\getfiledate{tables/classification_Full.tex}
```

PS: When the file does not exist the error is shown correctly as expected.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! A little more information might help other people figure out how to help you.  Most likely a link to whatever external-files and a minimum working example of some kind would assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue happens when the file name is being printed.

The simplest workaround, if you have no special need such as macros in the file name, is

```
\getfiledate{\detokenize{tables/classification_Full.tex}}
```

Otherwise, the string has to be made in a different fashion:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{clifte_test.tex}
Hello
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{getfiledate}

\makeatletter
\def\gfd@prefix@a#1{%
  \ifcsempty{gfd@marker}{}{\gfd@marker@a}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \unexpanded{\gfd@prefix\space\textcolor{\gfd@filenamecolor}}%
    {\noexpand\ttfamily\noexpand\detokenize{#1}}%
    \unexpanded{\space\gfd@postfix\space}%
  }\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\getfiledate{clifte_test.tex}

\newcommand{\MYPREFIX}{clifte}% just to see macros can be used
\getfiledate{\MYPREFIX_test.tex}

\end{document}
```

I added `\noexpand\ttfamily` so the file name is printed in monospaced font (which is not the case in the original definition). Remove the two tokens if you don't want monospaced font; however, if you do, remember to do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or the underscore would not be printed (a dot would appear instead). The same if you use the shorter workaround (and no macros in the file name).

[image]

Comment: Curious package. Tons of options to change colors, add frames and you can even add a heart before the time, but nothing to safely print a file name.